# Where about is a 'low brow'?

Tags: word-meaning

The following is from 'The Blackhouse' by Peter May

> The real bastard was a short, stocky man with thick, sandy hair
>   Brylcreemed back from a **low brow**.

I know what a 'brow' is. I also looked up a 'low brow' in the dictionary but it doesn't have a physical definition [here](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/low+brow)  Where about is a 'low' brow located on person's brow in a physical sense? Is it somewhere right above one's eyebrow?

Comment: Did you look up *brow* in a dictionary? It's between your eyebrows and your hairline like any other shape of brow.

Comment: @The Photon  Then where about is the 'low' brow? Can you Brylcreem your hair back from a low brow?

Comment: Yes, you can grease your hair back, and you can do so "from" a low brow (forehead).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "low" brow refers to a forehead which is relatively short in height as measured from the eyebrows (from the top of the orbits of the skull) to the hair-line (e.g. Neanderthal). A high brow is just the opposite. Traditionally (pseudo-science) these cranial features have been associated with lower and higher intelligence, respectively.

[image: rendering of a Neanderthal man]

Comment: I didn't know it refers to the length not upper or lower location. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Brow is not eyebrows but just about the level of them. You can have a prominent brow which implies the brow bone protrudes. 
Those are physical characteristics.

Low-brow could describe nonphysical characteristics.
adjective -not highly intellectual or cultured.

High-brow - cultured, intelligent, high society